# macro extension does not run commands synchronously

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I want to make a shortcut which can insert the current date at the 72 position of the line in VScode.
I let the Cursor go to the Pos 72 first and used an extension to get the current date.
But, the customize extension did not wait for the Cursor moving, and the date appeared at the current position. 
It seems like Asynchronous happens when the macros run.
Here is my code

```
"addDate": [
  "cursorLineEnd",
  {"command": "type", "args": {"text": "                                                                        "}},
  "cursorLineStart",
  {"command": "cursorMove", "args": {"to": "right", "by": "character", "value": 72}},
  {"command": "type", "args": {"text": "AD"}},
  "editor.action.trimTrailingWhitespace",
  {"command": "insertDateString.insertDate"},
]
```

The `{"command": "insertDateString.insertDate"},` did not wait the cursorMove finished and worked directly.
Is there any ways like "promise...then" or priority setting that let PG runs by sequence?
Thanks

Comment: What macro extension are you using?  There are better ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using the macro command [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command).  It properly handles synchronous commands.  So using multi-command, put this into your settings.josn:

```
 "multiCommand.commands": [

   {
      "command": "multiCommand.addDate",
      "sequence": [
        "cursorLineEnd",
        {
          "command": "type", 
          "args": {   "text": "                                                                        "
          }
        },
        "cursorLineStart",
        {"command": "cursorMove", "args": {"to": "right", "by": "character", "value": 72}},
        {"command": "type", "args": {"text": "AD"}},
        "editor.action.trimTrailingWhitespace",
        {"command": "insertDateString.insertDate"}
      ]
    }
  ]
```

and then your keybinding looks like this:

```
 {
    "key": "alt+d",                  // whatever you choose
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { "command": "multiCommand.addDate" },
    // "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
```

And it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks!  I have been used the extension of the [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros) , In [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command), it worked perfectly.